# A better way of putting allot of information into an SQL database, than querying in URL

Tags: php, mysql, bash

I have a simple php script set up, through which I put information into an MySQL database by the following URL query:

https://www.thesite.com/addinformation.php?WHERE_TO_LABEL_IT_AS&WHAT_TEXT_TO_ADD"

I call it from bash by simply using wget

```
wget --no-check-certificate --user=username --password='password' --delete-after https://www.thesite.com/addinformation.php?$LABELVARIABLE&$STRINGVARIABLE"
```

It works for my needs, but I would now like to use a similar way to add large chunks of text into the database. Perhaps even whole text files. What method would you recommend I read up on to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could save your content to a file, and post it using either *wget* or *curl*.

```
$ wget --post-file=<file path>
```

or

```
$ curl --data-binary @<file path>
```